# Select between two minimum keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

could someone help me select the minimum value between two keys? For example, if I have the list of dictionaries:

```
results = [
  {
    "model": "short",
    "score": 34,
    "alt_score": 1
  }, 
  {
    "model": "med",
    "score": 22,
    "alt_score": 11
  }, 
  {
    "model": "tall",
    "score": 42,
    "alt_score": 90
  }, 
  {
    "model": "xtall",
    "score": 83,
    "alt_score": 15
  }, 
]
```

I want to select the dictionary that has the smallest `score` OR `alt_score`. I know how to find the dictionary w/ the smallest `score` or `alt_score` individually:

`min(results, key=lambda x:x['alt_score'])`

but I'm not sure how to look at two keys at once. I would need something like:

`min(results, key=lambda x:x['score', 'alt_score])`

or

`min(results, key=lambda x:x['score'] or x:x['alt_score'])`

the result should return:

```
{
  "model": "short",
  "score": 34,
  "alt_score": 1
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
min(results, key=lambda x:min(x['score'], x['alt_score']))
```

Lambdas can have pretty much any expression in them, including an internal call to `min()` to get whichever is smaller for the item, `score` or `alt_score`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this:

```
min(results, key=lambda x: min(x['score'], x['alt_score']))
```

Answer (score 1):

`min(results, key=lambda x:min(x['score'], x['alt_score']))`

x needs to reference each score for the inner min() comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
results = [
  {
    "model": "short",
    "score": 34,
    "alt_score": 1
  }, 
  {
    "model": "med",
    "score": 22,
    "alt_score": 11
  }, 
  {
    "model": "tall",
    "score": 42,
    "alt_score": 90
  }, 
  {
    "model": "xtall",
    "score": 83,
    "alt_score": 15
  }, 
]

print(min(results, key=lambda x:min(x['score'],x['alt_score'])))
```